# How to connect my host mysql in docker container?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, laradock

my.cnf configured = bind-address = 172.18.0.3(Docker Container ID) 
and bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in my host.
I try connecting from docker container.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

But not connecting local mysql.I get this error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect to your local database , you call give **host.docker.internal** in the place where we provide database url . Then give the db you want to specify along with db username and db password.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the docker0 interface IP address 
   run `ip route show | awk '/default/ {print $3}'` inside your container and check the ip address. try to connect on this IP address and port 3306.
2. If you have static a host IP address then you can also use host machine IP address to connect.